# Learning Python fast how can I protect some private connections from been exposed

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftp, credentials, python-module

Hi I'm new to the community and new to Python, experienced but rusty on other high level languages, so my question is simple.

I made a simple script to connect to a private ftp server, and retrieve daily information from it.

```
from ftplib import FTP

#Open ftp connection
#Connect to server to retrieve inventory
#Open ftp connection

def FTPconnection(file_name):

    ftp = FTP('ftp.serveriuse.com')
    ftp.login('mylogin', 'password')

#List the files in the current directory
    print("Current File List:")
    file = ftp.dir()
    print(file)


# # #Get the latest csv file from server
#     ftp.cwd("/pub")

    gfile = open(file_name, "wb")
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR '+ file_name, gfile.write)
    gfile.close()
    ftp.quit()
    
FTPconnection('test1.csv')
FTPconnection('test2.csv')
```

That's the whole script, it passes my credentials, and then calls the function **FTPconnection** on two different files I'm retrieving.

Then my other script that processes them has an import statement, as I tried to call this script as a module, what my import does it's just connect to the FTP server and fetch information.

```
import ftpconnect as ftpc
```

This is the on the other Python script, that does the processing.
It works but I want to improve it, so I need some guidance on best practices about how to do this, because in Spyder 4.1.5 I get an 'Module ftpconnect called but unused' warning ... so probably I am missing something here, I'm developing on MacOS using Anaconda and Python 3.8.5.

I'm trying to build an app, to automate some tasks, but I couldn't find anything about modules that guided me to better code, it simply says you have to import whatever .py file name you used and that will be considered a module ...
and my final question is how can you normally **protect private information(ftp credentials)** from being exposed? This has nothing to do to protect my code but the credentials.

Comment: Normally importing a module just defines functions and variables, and the script that imports it calls the functions. It's unusual for importing the module to actually do all the work like transfering files. Your IDE is assuming this is the case, so it warns when it doesn't see you never call any of the imported functions.

Comment: ok @Barmar, thanks for the insight, how can upvote your reply? so there is nothing else I can do, so will it work if instead of calling the functions on the ftpconnect.py script to call them in the one I use for processing, then how can I protect private info?
Those credentials, will suffice to use Unix permissions or there is another common practice?

Comment: My comment was just about the `Module ftpconnect called but unused` warning, nothing about credential storage.

Comment: You solve that by calling `ftpc.FTPconnection('test1.csv')` in the script that imports.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options for storing passwords and other secrets that a Python program needs to use, particularly a program that needs to run in the background where it can't just ask the user to type in the password.

Problems to avoid:

1. Checking the password in to source control where other developers or even the public can see it.
2. Other users on the same server reading the password from a configuration file or source code.
3. Having the password in a source file where others can see it over your shoulder while you are editing it.

### Option 1: SSH

This isn't always an option, but it's probably the best. Your private key is never transmitted over the network, SSH just runs mathematical calculations to prove that you have the right key.

In order to make it work, you need the following:

- The database or whatever you are accessing needs to be accessible by SSH. Try searching for "SSH" plus whatever service you are accessing. For example, ["ssh postgresql"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ssh-tunnels.html). If this isn't a feature on your database, move on to the next option.
- Create an account to run the service that will make calls to the database, and [generate an SSH key](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2).
- Either add the public key to the service you're going to call, or create a local account on that server, and install the public key there.

### Option 2: Environment Variables

This one is the simplest, so it might be a good place to start. It's described well in the [Twelve Factor App](https://12factor.net/config). The basic idea is that your source code just pulls the password or other secrets from environment variables, and then you configure those environment variables on each system where you run the program. It might also be a nice touch if you use default values that will work for most developers. You have to balance that against making your software "secure by default".

Here's an example that pulls the server, user name, and password from environment variables.

```
import os

server = os.getenv('MY_APP_DB_SERVER', 'localhost')
user = os.getenv('MY_APP_DB_USER', 'myapp')
password = os.getenv('MY_APP_DB_PASSWORD', '')

db_connect(server, user, password)
```

Look up how to set environment variables in your operating system, and consider running the service under its own account. That way you don't have sensitive data in environment variables when you run programs in your own account. When you do set up those environment variables, take extra care that other users can't read them. Check file permissions, for example. Of course any users with root permission will be able to read them, but that can't be helped. If you're using systemd, look at the [service unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html), and be careful to use `EnvironmentFile` instead of `Environment` for any secrets. `Environment` values can be viewed by any user with `systemctl show`.

### Option 3: Configuration Files

This is very similar to the environment variables, but you read the secrets from a text file. I still find the environment variables more flexible for things like deployment tools and continuous integration servers. If you decide to use a configuration file, Python supports several formats in the standard library, like [JSON](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html), [INI](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html), [netrc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/netrc.html), and [XML](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html). You can also find external packages like [PyYAML](https://pypi.org/project/PyYAML/) and [TOML](https://pypi.org/project/toml/). Personally, I find JSON and YAML the simplest to use, and YAML allows comments.

Three things to consider with configuration files:

1. Where is the file? Maybe a default location like `~/.my_app`, and a command-line option to use a different location.
2. Make sure other users can't read the file.
3. Obviously, don't commit the configuration file to source code. You might want to commit a template that users can copy to their home directory.

### Option 4: Python Module

Some projects just put their secrets right into a Python module.

```
# settings.py
db_server = 'dbhost1'
db_user = 'my_app'
db_password = 'correcthorsebatterystaple'
```

Then import that module to get the values.

```
# my_app.py
from settings import db_server, db_user, db_password

db_connect(db_server, db_user, db_password)
```

One project that uses this technique is [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/). Obviously, you shouldn't commit `settings.py` to source control, although you might want to commit a file called `settings_template.py` that users can copy and modify.

I see a few problems with this technique:

1. Developers might accidentally commit the file to source control. Adding it to `.gitignore` reduces that risk.
2. Some of your code is not under source control. If you're disciplined and only put strings and numbers in here, that won't be a problem. If you start writing logging filter classes in here, stop!

If your project already uses this technique, it's easy to transition to environment variables. Just move all the setting values to environment variables, and change the Python module to read from those environment variables.

Comment: Wow thank you for this information @kinshukdua, yes I am learning Django too, and I was considering doing that, when the app is more mature and can be online, but in these early stages, I was just developing locally but I was curious about how to protect the credentials, so these information is great, I never considered using environment variables, because I didn't even touch the sys or os modules yet(roughly just used them twice) ... At this early stage, is all in one directory and I'm more focused on making improvements to the code, but it's good to know, this can be done this way.

Comment: No problem! Please upvote or select it as the answer if it solved your issue, so people searching for it in the future can find it. Happy Coding!

Comment: Well that was exactly what I was trying to do but as the module is just another .py file, I thought you could make it harder, like encrypting and decryptyng or using something like PDO in MySQL, I remember in php doing exactly that with includes, but Python is like Basic, more exposed, so I did some research and couldn't find anything of the sort. @kinshukdua